# Call URL with Basic Authentication with Accept and Content Type

Tags: json, rest, xamarin

I have the following code in my mobile application, and it fetches data properly. myURL is symbolic only.

```
        var client = new RestClient("http://myURL/");
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("efgh", "ijkl");
        var request2 = new RestRequest("rest/humantask/task/assigned/Jane");

        request2.AddHeader ("Accept", "application/json");
        request2.AddHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

However, I would like to see json objects on my browser. Once I call the URL as follows, it does not return anything. What am I missing? or is there a tool (extension) which I could use?

myURL/rest/humantask/task/assigned/Jane

Comment: There are many extensions for Chrome and Firefox for displaying and editing JSON.  Have you searched for them?

Comment: Could you please give me a couple of their names which you recommend?

Comment: http://jsonview.com/

Comment: Hello Jason, my question is how/where to set up authorization(username, password) and header when I call my URL?

Comment: Hello Jason, nevermind, I have found a solution by using postman, there is username and password and also header entries. Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution by using postman, there is username and password sections, and also header entries.

Postman Link could be found in the following link:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

[image]

Answer (score 1):

hello for crome i preffer JSON Editor Extenstion you can also edit JSON Result. you can check [JSONEditor](http://jsoneditoronline.org)

Comment: Hello Burak, my question is how/where to set up authorization(password, username) and header when I call my URL?

Comment: Nevermind, I have found a solution by using postman, there is username and password sections, and also header entries.